# Show $2 \mid \dim(V) \Leftrightarrow \exists u \in \mathrm{End}(V)$, $\ker u = \mathrm{Im} u$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ a vector space with $n = \dim V$.

$(\Leftarrow)$ it is trivial because if $\exists u \in \mathrm{End}(V)$, $\ker u = \mathrm{Im} u$ then the rank formula gives

$$ \dim(V) = 2 \dim( \ker(u)) \Rightarrow 2 \mid \dim(V) $$

For the "$(\Rightarrow)$" I don't get it. I thought of building such endomorphism $u$ but I don't know how.. If anyone can give me a hint, I'd be grateful. Thanks you

Comment: You can't think of a projection that has half the space in its kernel and is the identity on the rest?